# Convert dynamic web project in Java to Maven Project

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, eclipse-luna

I am using Eclipse Luna. I have a working dynamic web project. I need to convert this to a Maven Project.

However, creating a new Maven Project and copying the source files is not an option. Is there an easy way to do this in Eclipse?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Project context menu -> Configure-> Convert to Maven Project.

Comment: Much better answer :)

Comment: Thanks. Simple solution.